# help me understand files and blocks count on booting

Tags: files, fstab, fsck

On booting my laptop, right after BIOS is loaded I see on my screen:

`/dev/sda1: clean, 116918/19275776 files, 66284199/77094912 blocks`

I have two questions:

1. If I'm seeing that information, is it a sign that something is dying/already broken? It started appearing 3 days ago.
2. The first number to the left of the forward slash for both files and blocks it's with each booting different (I mean 116918 and 66284199). What do those numbers indicate? Is it a problem?

Comment: No, your laptop isn't broken. This is output from a program called `fsck` that checks for errors and correct them if any are found.

Answer (score 0):

This is the output of a filesystem check at boot for the `/dev/sda1` partition. `fsck` (actually probably `e2fsck` if it's an ext4 filesystem, which is the default for modern Ubuntu installations) is the program which carries out the checks. This is set to happen after a configurable number of reboots, or after a certain time period. It can also be triggered if you had to switch your computer off without properly shutting down, such as if you had to shut down by holding the power button in.

The piece of information that is most relevant is the word 'clean', which indicates that everything's in working order. So there's nothing to worry about.

The files and blocks part of the output show how many of the available files and blocks are in use. The files part actually applies to inodes, which are the underlying filesystem location for a file. So you're using 116918 out of the 19275776 available files spaces, and 66284199 of the available 77094912 blocks.